What makes a sector of a disk slower and harder to process?
I did a surface test with dark green Hard Disk Sentinel Pro 6.20 and it says that some sectors (represented with dark green in the screenshot below) are slower and harder to process. What makes a sector of a disk slower and harder to process? I wasn't using the disk during the test.

For completeness, here is the disk performance vs. position plot:

SMART info:


Hard Disk Sentinel Help - Surface Test

@Blindspots thanks, it mentions "Darker green color means that the sectors are slower and harder to process (read or write depending on the test type) but they are still good. Having some (especially random) darker green blocks are completely acceptable unless they form a continuous, larger area (especially with yellow/red blocks near", but doesn't state what makes a sector of a disk slower and harder to process. Or maybe I missed sth?

Basically you can extrapolate that to mean maybe nothing maybe impending doom. If there are other not good indicators then be fearful. If not then maybe it is nothing (or it isn't). Sounds like the test hammers the drive so you could hammer it some more and see if it gets more upset or not. I don't know that tool so can't comment.

@JoepvanSteen SMART info:
https://i.sstatic.net/rU8nSBrk.png Thx!

basically wear and tear on the sectors, it like a carpet some parts showing sign of wear which will likely fail some day.

A "slow" read might mean that the ECC (Error Correction Code) could not correct the read error (too many bits are incorrect), so the read was retried (which extends the time to complete the operation).
When the retries are unsuccessful, then the read operation fails, and the drive or host typically marks that sector as "bad".
But a successful retry (even if correction is needed) keeps that sector as "good".
I have no idea as what a "slow" write could be. Typically a sector write cannot cause an error other than an error to locate the proper sector.
Adjacent/consecutive bad sectors typically indicate a surface flaw such as a scratched surface.
